# Ember - liquid fire - transitions.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have installed liquid-fire. Set it all up. And it works between 2 files in the templates folder.

transitions.js

```
export default function(){
  this.transition(
    this.fromRoute('test1'),
    this.toRoute('test2'),

    this.use('toRight'),
    this.reverse('toLeft')
  );
}
```

router.js

```
Router.map(function() {

  this.route('test1', function() {});
  this.route('test2', function() {});

});
```

application.hbs

```
{{liquid-outlet}}
```

test1.hbs

```
<h1>test1</h1>
<br>
{{#link-to 'test2'}} test 2 {{/link-to}}
```

test2.hbs

```
<h1>test2</h1>
<br>
{{#link-to 'test1'}} back to test 1 {{/link-to}}
```

This works fine. I get a nice slide effect between the 2 pages.

But when I move test2 into a folder, no matter what I do, the pages link, but there is no nice transition.

I have tried the below code:

transitions.js

```
export default function(){
  this.transition(
    this.fromRoute('test1'),
    this.toRoute('cakes.test2'),

    this.use('toRight'),
    this.reverse('toLeft')
  );
}
```

router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('test1', function() {});


    this.route('cakes', function() {
      this.route('test2', function() {});
    });

});
```

test1.hbs

```
<h1>test1</h1>
<br>
{{#link-to 'cakes.test2'}} test 2 {{/link-to}}
```

test2.hbs

```
<h1>test2</h1>
<br>
{{#link-to 'test1'}} back to test 1 {{/link-to}}
```

The pages change, so the link works- and you can visit the url cakes/test2 in the browser also. But there is no nice slide transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define specific transition animations between different level routes.

What you can do is define a transition between test1 route and cakes route, since they are on the same level.

```
  this.transition(
    this.fromRoute('test1'),
    this.toRoute('cakes'),

    this.use('toRight'),
    this.reverse('toLeft')
  );
```

This would then activate the animation when you go from test1 route to cakes.test2